# Не понимаю, почему не работает

Tags: java, javafx

При попытке выполнить данный код программа "Не отвечает". Как это исправить?

```
if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный"){
    System.out.println("Обычный режим запущен");
    time.progressProperty().bind(progress);
    normalTime=normalTime*60;
    normalTime=normalTime*1000;
    for(int row=0;row<100;row++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2700000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        progress.setValue(progress.getValue()+0.01);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну ведь вы останавливаете текущий процесс на 45 минут. Вот и результат

Comment: А потом ещё на 45... а потом ещё на 45. И так 100 раз.  75 часов.

Comment: Блин, а ведь точно. Спасибо огромное